# JavaFX ListView edit TextFieldListCell

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on a client-server solution and I have a ListView with my connected clients. The user should be able to remotely rename the clients just by editing the name in the ListView. I have read a lot about editing ListView cells, but I haven't found any good example where I can just change a member attribute of my class. Most of the examples are with a list of strings, and in my opinion this is not modern software development, if the items inside of the ListView are more than just strings.

**What I want to do is to change the attribute `name` inside of my client.**

```
class Client {
    private String name;
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public String setName(String val){
        name = val;
    }
}
```

*I don't care, if I have to implement the member `name` as a JavaFX property (in fact I already have done that, but left it out for readability and simplicity).*

### Failed attempt to use the TextFieldListCell Factory

In case you are interested, I have tried to use the TextFieldListCell cell factory:

```
this.listViewClients.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell
 .forListView(new NetworkClientStringConverter(this.clientController)));
```

But there are some tricky things i found out:

- Every time the name changes, I can't just access the object. Apparently what I am supposed to do is to create a new client and return it (`fromString`).

  - I solved this, by passing my client controller to the `StringConverter`. (This is not nice, I would prefer to just have access to the client I am changing.)
- Still, the name does not change.

Comment: Yes, I said that already :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just noticed that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit tricky using the standard `TextFieldListCell`, but the following seems to work.

Assume throughout this question there's a `Client` model class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Client {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }


    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

}
```

(fwiw I think everything still applies here if you use standard Java Bean properties instead of JavaFX Properties).

Create a converter class that references the cell:

```
public class ClientConverter extends StringConverter<Client> {
    private final ListCell<Client> cell;
    public ClientConverter(ListCell<Client> cell) {
        this.cell = cell ;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Client client) {
        return client.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Client fromString(String string) {
        Client client = cell.getItem();
        client.setName(string);
        return client ;
    }

}
```

and then you can do

```
listViewClients.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    TextFieldListCell<Client> cell = new TextFieldListCell<>();
    cell.setConverter(new ClientConverter(cell));
    return cell ;
});
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class EditableListView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Client> listViewClients = new ListView<>();
        for (int i= 1 ; i <= 20; i++) {
            Client c = new Client();
            c.setName("Client "+i);
            listViewClients.getItems().add(c);
        }

        listViewClients.setEditable(true);

        listViewClients.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            TextFieldListCell<Client> cell = new TextFieldListCell<>();
            cell.setConverter(new ClientConverter(cell));
            return cell ;
        });

        // debug:

        Button debug = new Button("Show clients");
        debug.setOnAction(e -> listViewClients.getItems().stream().map(Client::getName).forEach(System.out::println));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listViewClients, null, null, debug, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static class ClientConverter extends StringConverter<Client> {
        private final ListCell<Client> cell;
        public ClientConverter(ListCell<Client> cell) {
            this.cell = cell ;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(Client client) {
            return client.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Client fromString(String string) {
            Client client = cell.getItem();
            client.setName(string);
            return client ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This feels like a bit of a hack though, because it's not really the job of the `StringConverter` to update the data in the model (`Client`) class. I would probably favor just creating the cell implementation from scratch here.

It's a little more code, but this feels safer:

```
public class ClientListCell extends ListCell<Client> {
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    public ClientListCell() {
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        });
        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            getItem().setName(textField.getText());
            setText(textField.getText());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        });
        setGraphic(textField);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Client client, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(client, empty);
        if (isEditing()) {
            textField.setText(client.getName());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        } else {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(client.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(getItem().getName());
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(getItem().getName());
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

and the SSCCE using this cell implementation is

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditableListView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Client> listViewClients = new ListView<>();
        for (int i= 1 ; i <= 20; i++) {
            Client c = new Client();
            c.setName("Client "+i);
            listViewClients.getItems().add(c);
        }

        listViewClients.setEditable(true);

        listViewClients.setCellFactory(lv -> new ClientListCell());

        // debug:

        Button debug = new Button("Show clients");
        debug.setOnAction(e -> listViewClients.getItems().stream().map(Client::getName).forEach(System.out::println));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listViewClients, null, null, debug, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I didn't want to go for cell factory is that I apparently can not separate it easily into an own class. It's a lot of code to just implement it inline? Will look into it tomorrow, thanks James.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to rewrite that as a standalone class. I'll update when I'm back at the computer.

Comment: FYI: I created my own StringConverter class (actually it's almost the same), and because it's not internal (or lambda), I had to pass the client controller over. Maybe I could try to tweak it using cell, instead of the controller.

Comment: You should be able just to pass the reference to the cell to it.

Comment: Updated demonstrating both of those.

Comment: the code looks nice, I still have a problem when editing (when I double click, the text disappears and I can't enter new text). I will look into it, maybe I find something.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct, because the bug has nohing to do with my problem (at least not directly).

Comment: well, a stateful converter is rather ... dirty? @ElMac if I understand you correctly, you want a ListView with features of a TableColumn? f.i. ListView<Client, String>? That's not supported (as you  noticed :-) but can be implemented with not too much hazzle (merge a c&p from TableColumn into a custom ListView, and implement a custom ListCell). On the other hand you might want to opt for the simple way out and use a single-column table (hide the header).

Comment: @ElMac paddling back: it _is_ a hazzle when editing is involved ... the typing is hard-coded (celll must have same parameter type as the list, resulting in methods/events carrying that type - couldn't find any way to get around ...)

Comment: Well this is the reason, why I have tried to avoid in-cell editing (it's just implemented really weird). In the end I have ended up using a Dialog which is probably also more user-friendly and gives me more control. I still want to get a working answer here, for completeness sake.

Comment: The `ClientListCell` approach is cleaner, for the reason @kleopatra mentioned (stateful converter...). I updated with a complete working example which uses that version.

Comment: cleaner is a very relative term <g> (by-passing edit handlers isn't overly clean either) - looks like the options are about choosing one of several dirt-holes. Or implement a (nearly) complete new ListView. Currently experimenting with custom edit events in a custom ListView and a custom ListCell (requires reflective access cell.setEditing) .. yet another dirty hole ;-)

Comment: @ElMac dialogs are considered suboptimal UX .. so sounds more like a last resort

Comment: Ah, not bypassing the edit handlers is a fairly easy fix, no? But I should do some actual work...

Comment: hmm .. how would that be easy? You already changed an item property at the time the handler might see the event (if I understand your code correctly :-)

Comment: @kleopatra well, compared to in-cell editing, a dialog might be a lot better because you can show the user informations about what exactly he is doing. In a client-server application, the developer has to try to tell the user when a change happened while he was editing and will "overwrite" his changes. While there are a lot of studies about how distractions deteriorate human performance, most of them are not specifically talking about dialogs (and most of the ones which are, handle web and mobile applications). It's a nice input from you tho, but a discussion would be out of this topic. ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Oh, yes, I see the problem now. :). I was just thinking all that was really needed was a call to `commitEdit(...)`, but the parameter becomes a problem (because the "item" doesn't change identity). Meh. Stupid editing API. FWIW I never really use `onEditCommit` and associated API anyway: update the model and if you need to know when something changes, observe the model. Anyway, I *really* need to do some work...